# Add dynamically svg, manipulate and add to DOM in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a html page that pops up a modal dialog with a .svg file in it.

The svg file (for now) in a static content folder.

I want to load the svg file in memory, do some in memory edits, and then add it dynamically into the popup page.

How can this be done with AngularJS (using the {{}} and filling/manipulating in the controller) ?

Comment: AngularJS and SVG ... May the Force be with you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Using AngularJS UI, having a good basic template for showing a modal dialog (see modal section in http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap).

One fix I had to make, was to call $scope.$apply to have show the dynamic injected html.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat='process in myProcesses.ProcessInstances.ProcessInstance'>
    <div class="myprocesses-row-wrapper">
        <div class="myprocesses-row">
            <div class="myprocesses-process-title">{{process.id}}</div>
            <div class="myprocesses-process-startedby">
                Started by: (dummy)
                <button class="btn pull-right" ng-click="open(process)">Show diagram</button>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--modal dialog to show the svg -->
<div modal="shouldBeOpen" close="close()" options="opts">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>Process diagram</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div compile="svgData"></div> <!--custom compile directive, to inject html directly-->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-warning cancel" ng-click="close()">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
'use strict';

    app.controller('MyProcessesController',
        function MyProcessesController($scope, $rootScope, $log, myService) {
            $rootScope.contentTitle = "My processes";
            $scope.myProcesses = myService.getMyProcesses();

            $scope.open = function (process) {
                //TODO: temp hack to load the svg, because current service does not give us the svg yet
                $('<div>').load("/Content/svg/svgexample.svg", function (data) {
                    $scope.svgData = data;
                    $scope.shouldBeOpen = true;
                    $scope.$apply(); // this is neccessary to show the dialog immediately
                });
            };

            $scope.close = function () {
                $scope.shouldBeOpen = false;
            };

            $scope.opts = {
                backdropFade: true,
                dialogFade: true
            };
        });
```